# Rotation of an object along 3 axis to match given path

Tags: arithmetic, 3d, rotations

I have 2 points in 3d space, p1 and p2, and need to rotate a long object (long on x-axis) along its 3 axis (first x, then y and finally z) for it to be aligned to the p1-p2 line.
Knowing both p1 and p2 coordinates, and the object's centre and rotation axis being exactly between p1 and p2, what would be rx, ry and rz ?

The rotation axis is a world axis and does not rotate with the object. Rotation applies first rx then ry then rz.

Initial situation:
[image: Initial situation]

Desired situation:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the *world space joint axes* are the ones being rotated around, you are basically solving $$M_1M_2M_3 v_1 = v_2$$
where $v_1$ is the position of whatever before rotation and $v_2$ the position after rotation and:

$$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}{v_1}_x\\{v_1}_y\\{v_1}_z\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}{v_2}_x\\{v_2}_y\\{v_2}_z\end{bmatrix}$$
and the matrices for rotation:
$$M_1 =\begin{bmatrix}a_1&b_1&0\\-b_1&a_1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},M_2 =\begin{bmatrix}a_2&0&b_2\\0&1&0\\-b_2&0&a_2\end{bmatrix},M_3 =\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&a_3&b_3\\0&-b_3&a_3\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$${a_i}^2 + {b_i}^2 = 1, i \in\{1,2,3\}$$

I am kind of sure this does not have any unique solution.

say the ortsvektors for $$P_2 = [3,5,7]^T\\ P_1 = [1,2,3]^T$$ then the $v_2$ to aim for should be $$v_2 = P_2-P_1 = [3-1,5-2,7-3]^T = [2,3,4]^T$$

Comment: Thanks ! Excuse me for this very basic question but what does the last line mean (1, i E...) ?

Comment: @LaurentCrivello: The last line means that sum of squares of $a$ and $b$ in each matrix should be 1. That's basically the same equation as $\sin(w)^2 + \cos(w)^2 = 1$ in trigonometry for angles which you maybe remember from like high school or when it's introduced.

Comment: Mmhhh, so I could take a=1 and b=0 in each matrix, but it wouldn't give me per se the right answer. Still figuring out to what v1 and v2 apply (v1 = object vector before change and v2=p1->p2 line ?) and how to find the right a and b.

Comment: There could potentially be many different solutions, but a=1 b=0 in each would be rotation with 0 degrees which probably does not solve it. This is just a way to express the problem with mathematics, then you need to find a suitable solver for it. Many times it is at least as hard to find a way to express a problem with mathematics than it is to find a method that solves it.

Comment: Ok. Let's me be more concrete so I can better understand your reasoning. Let's assume p1=(1,2,3) and p2=(3,5,7); What angles should I apply to the long object to match the p1->p2 line ? Really thanks for your patience.

Comment: $v_1$ is the vector to one of the endpoints of the rod, $v_2$ is the vector pointing where you want that endpoint to end up. Ah I see now, I first thought there was a point and not a line to aim the rod for. Well the expressions still make sense. We could make some minor adjustments to fit a line instead.

Comment: Would you mind applying your comments to my arbitrary situation (p1=1,2,3 and p2=3,5,7) as your maths skills seem 25'000 times more advanced than mine. I will then be a lens to replicate to other situations.

Comment: To get something parallell to the line between p1 p2 we should aim for a vector which is the difference between them. $3-1,5-2,7-3 = 2,3,4$

Comment: Vector is indeed easy to find, my issue is to find rx, ry and rz. According to the arbitrary situation, the rotation should be roughly rx=27.4, ry=140.7, rz=41.4. But I don't really understand how to apply your model to reach these values.

Comment: There's so many numerical optimization methods you could try. Basically a whole rather big subfield of mathematics you could try once you have gotten a way to describe what should be optimized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57588/discussion-between-laurent-crivello-and-mathreadler).

Comment: Thanks for having edited the answer with description of v2. What would be v1 in my example ?

Comment: $v_1$ will be the ortsvektor pointing out one end of the rod. We want to rotate one end of the rod so that it ends up pointing parallell to the line.